# Does death due to heart disease qualify as being diagnosed with heart disease?

Tags: insurance

I came across this question on a life insurance form:

> My biological parents or biological siblings have been diagnosed by a
>   member of the medical profession with any of the following: cancer,
>   heart disease, diabetes, kidney disease, Huntington's Disease, Marfan
>   Syndrome, or Lynch Syndrome

My father died with heart disease listed as the cause of death, but he was not *diagnosed* with heart disease. By the letter of the law, in this situation, would the answer to "does the above apply to me?" be yes or no?

Comment: The intent here is to show a family history for heart disease, so I believe the answer should be "yes".

Comment: But the question in the contract says *diagnosed*. If the company wanted to know about *any history at all*, they could and should have said that, and an argument over this would have to go against them because they're the ones who wrote the document.

Answer (score 1):

In interpretting the words of a contract, the courts might consult a dictionary to sort out potential ambiguities, but a dictionary would not provide that kind of information. Instead of appealing to an authoritative source,they are likely to perform a reasonable man analysis, asking what a reasonable man would think a  "diagnosis" is. There is no special term that refers to detection of a condition after death, and the literature is full of references to post_mortem diagnoses. A reasonable man would this understand that a diagnosis of a condition after death is still a diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

> in this situation, would the answer to "does the above apply to me?" be yes or no?

If none of your father's *prior* medical checks reflects heart disease (apropos of "*he was not diagnosed with heart disease*"), then you have merit in answering "*no*".

According to [this study from 2017](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5687260/), "*heart disease was **incorrectly** identified as the cause of death on 54.5%–85% of death certificates*" (emphasis added). Therefore, a death certificate alone would hardly be cognizable grounds for insurer's denial of coverage or for a higher premium under pretext of your father's alleged cause of death.

Penalizing insurers essentially for sloppy practices in medical reporting would be unreasonable and does not reflect the exposure a life insurance company is supposed to assess.